# MySQL workbench returns stored procedure with multiple rows, but from Java code, only one row is returned

Tags: mysql, jdbc, procedure, workbench

It is MYSQL, and the same stored procedure call in Workbench works fine, but from Java code, it always only return one row.

```
String sql = "{ CALL getList(?, ?, ?) }";

CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);
cs.setLong(1, key);
cs.setString(2, id);
cs.setInt(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
rtn = cs.getInt(3);             // this return as 1

while (rs.next()) {
     String name = rs.getString("name");
     String age= rs.getString("age");
     //.....
}
```

from this while loop, always and only return one row, it is very strange, spend hours, no clue yet, please advice what may be wrong, the hint is that the MYSQL is old version 5.3, and Java is old version JDK 1.6.

Anybody have experience to deal with it, please advice, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem and shows how you conclude there is only one row.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you have, you need to also implement the add() method. Try this:

```
String sql = "{ CALL getList(?, ?, ?) }";

CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);
cs.setLong(1, key);
cs.setString(2, id);
cs.setInt(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
rtn = cs.getInt(3);           

while(rs.next()) {
    String name = add(rs.getString("name"));
    String age= add(rs.getString("age"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure what this add refer to, I can get one row, and the problem is that is only get one row, not multiple rows, would you please advice, thanks.

Comment: You have this: rs.getString("name"); I proposed that instead you use this: add(rs.getString("name")); . Are you saying you tried it and it still does not work?

Comment: The problem is that rs.next() did not able to pull out next row, but the code is inside the loop, I am confused of what this add() method refer to, I did not implement it, and need to understand it first, thank you for your quick response.

Comment: How do you come to conclusion that the OP needs to write some method called `add()`?